# matrix and vector template classes in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, matrix

```
#include <array>

template <typename T>
class Vector4<T> {
    std::array<T, 4> _a; // or 'T _a[4];'?
};

template <typename T>
class Matrix4<T> {
    std::array<T, 16> _a; // or 'T _a[16];'?
    //Vector4<T> row0; // or should i use this instead
    //Vector4<T> row1; // it makes other code easier but how
    //Vector4<T> row2; // can i implement something like 
    //Vector4<T> row3; // std::array::data()?
};
```

thanks

edit: ya its for 3d game programming... so i will need more then boost matrix can provide anyway like rotate and translate and invert etc...

Comment: do write the question outside the code block, it's kinda hard to see what you're actually asking.

Comment: Well, ublas is a linear algebra library. So it's designed for operations like matrix product.
Rotation, translations are nothing more than matrix products.
So if that want you want to do, then I strongly recommend going to ublas.

Comment: Actually, though I haven't done any tests, knowing the size's of matrices at compile-time can help the compiler optimize. Game's don't need generic run-time sized matrices.

Answer (score 4):

The way you want to do it, would be

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > my_matrix(4, std::vector<int>(4));
```

However, I would rather use ublas from boost if you want to handle matricies:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

int main () {
    using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
    matrix<double> m (3, 3);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m.size1 (); ++ i)
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < m.size2 (); ++ j)
            m (i, j) = 3 * i + j;
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

The example is from their website http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using dynamically allocated matrices when he is only interested in 4x4 matrices...

Comment: Indeed, the compiler will be able to optimize much better if it knows the size of the matrices it's working on at compile-time. I'd use a `std::/boost::array`.

Answer (score 3):

I've found [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialCore.html) to be the most straightforward of the C++ linear algebra libraries, and it contains templates for fixed and variable dimension vectors and matrices.  Like Boost, it's a pure template "library" so there are no libs to build / include, but I find it to be more complete and significantly more performant than Boost's ublas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would want std::array _a[4], as you will create 4 arrays with that.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a standard `std::vector` class.  If you need something specifically for linear algebra, I'd suggest looking into boost ublas.

Comment: vector allocates data on heap by default, not a good choice for a small size data object like fixed-size vector/matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Boost ublas is a great library, but is not optimized if all you want to is 4-D stuff. I would recommend keeping the two classes independent:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector4<T> {
    T _a[4];
};

template <typename T>
class Matrix4<T> {
    T _m[4][4];
};
```

You can always cast a pointer to a row (`_m[i]`) into a Vector4<> if needed. To get a column vector though you will need an adapter class like ublas uses.

Comment: Why not makes the matrix out of an array of vector instead of casting ?

Comment: i would like to know too... also the nvidia sdk matrix class uses T _m[16] instead of T _m[4][4]